# exist bin, conflict bin/bundle in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran the below command and I got this error. I have no clue how to remove it.

```
$ rake rails:update:bin
```

DEPRECATION WARNING: Running update:bin with the rails: namespace is deprecated                                                                                                                 in favor of app: namespace. Run bin/rails app:update:bin instead. (called from l                                                                                                                oad at C:/Ruby24/bin/rake:23)

```
    exist  bin
    conflict  bin/bundle
<ktop/vpn/bin/bundle? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

Even when I press `h` and enter, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, but deprecation warning. It means in the future this command won't be supported.

You are offered also to run `bin/rails app:update:bin` instead.

**Updated:**

You are asked about what do you want to do with files' changes.

`(enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]` it's kind of standard for terminal apps for making decisions. The options are:

- Y - yes (default one, just press Enter for it)
- n - no (leave current file without changes)
- a - all (apply all changes)
- q - quit
- d - diff
- h - help

In your case you can choose `a` to update all bins.

Comment: I ran the other command but again I am seeing `<ktop/vpn/bin/bundle? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] `

Comment: I press a and enter it takes me to the new line. Nothing happens.

Comment: As I understand you run Rails on Windows. On Linux it has to acts as I answered. Try just to press Enter for each file.